# How to make a car go down a ramp at contest velocity even when the angle of the ramp is changed

Tags: friction, velocity

This is a high school project, I need to make a car go down a ramp at a contest velocity even when the angle of the ramp is changed, I was hoping if anyone could help me, figure out some way of doing this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to [Physics.SE]. Please include more specifics, like the ramp design or sketches in order to understand the problem at hand. I don't know what "contest velocity" is (unless you mean "a velocity contest"). Also why would the car won't go down a ramp if the angle is changed? Please elaborate more on this point.

Comment: I think this is engineering rather then physics. You need some form of [speed governor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Governor_(device)).

Comment: The project is to have a car go down a ramp with a ticker tape attached to the back of car, normally when the car is on the ramp and you let go the car would increase its velocity as it goes down the ramp. What I am trying to say/do is when I let go of the car i want to travel down the ramp at a contest speed instead of speeding up/slowing down.

Comment: Do you mean constant?

Comment: yes sorry my mistake